# Twitter Flume data not in readable format

Tags: hadoop, twitter, flume, flume-ng, flume-twitter

My twitter data is not in readable format. I fetched twitter data using flume, which i am trying to read using hive tables. But i can't see proper data in hdfs.     Below are the details:

flume-env.sh -

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera
FLUME_CLASSPATH="/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.8.0-1.cdh5.8.0.p0.42/lib/flume-ng/lib/flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

twitter.conf -

```
    TwitterAgent.sources = Twitter
    TwitterAgent.channels = MemChannel
    TwitterAgent.sinks = HDFS

    TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type=org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource
    TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.channels = MemChannel
    TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerKey = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.consumerSecret = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessToken = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.accessTokenSecret = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

    TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = hadoop, bigdata, data science

    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.channel = MemChannel
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.type = hdfs
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.path = hdfs://opt:8020/user/flume/tweets
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.fileType = DataStream
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.writeFormat = Text
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.batchSize = 100
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollSize = 0
    TwitterAgent.sinks.HDFS.hdfs.rollCount = 100

    TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.type = memory
    TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.capacity = 100
    TwitterAgent.channels.MemChannel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

When i do less one of the files:

[image]

Can someone tell me where i am going wrong? I need this data in readable format for hive table.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Just changed 
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type=org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource
to
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource